# Can I dynamically disable a drilldown in Siebel 7.8?

Tags: siebel, drilldown

I have a list applet with a drilldown in one of the columns, and I want to enable or disable it based on another field's value. Something like a [dynamic drilldown](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B31104_02/books/DevDep/DevDep_PickMvg7.html), but instead of choosing a different view, I want to disable the navigation for some of the records.

Can this be done in Siebel 7.8?

Ideally without server scripting... and definitely without ugly browser scripting hacks, please.

I have tried creating a dynamic drilldown, but it doesn't work because I have to specify a target view in my parent default drilldown. If I use an inactive view for that, then the whole dynamic drilldown is ignored and Siebel simply uses the one with the next sequence number.

I can think of a couple of ways to implement it, but both are far from ideal:

- Writing some server script to detect the drilldown event before it happens, and abort it if needed with a RaiseErrorText message. It should be doable... but I'd rather disable the drilldown than throw an ugly error to my users.
- Placing the drilldown in a calculated field, and make it have no text when there should be no navigation. If there is no text, there is nothing the users can click to drilldown, right? But I would have to add a new column just for the drilldown, which would be confusing for the users.

Comment: At first blush it seems that your second possible solution should work, but maybe I'm misunderstanding. Some clarification questions: **1)** Based on the value of _Field A_, _Field B_ may or may not have(allow) a drilldown? **2)** If _Field B_ is not allowed to be drilled down on, **does it (or could it) still have a value** (just not be drillable)?  [EDIT: Maybe I need to clarify how to properly write a comment....]

Comment: @Moonpie it's a Contacts screen, and the drilldown is currently on the Name field. I want to allow the drilldown only if another field has certain value... for example, only when Age is > 50. And yes, both fields will always have a value. So I thought of creating the drilldown in a new calculated field, something like `IIF([Age]>50, 'Click here to drilldown', '')`. But it's an ugly solution.

Comment: I'm not where I can check this out in Siebel, and I can't recall this information: If you make a field _Read Only_ and it has a drilldown, can you still drill down?

Comment: Yes, you can drilldown. The Name field with my drilldown is actually read only in my applet (although writeable at BC level).

Comment: Well, there go my "brilliant" ideas! :^)  I'll have to think more on this one.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any scripting. There are 2 ways.
First way is using toggle applet.
1.Main Applet will have the drill down down object. And Toggle applet will not have the drill down objects.
2.Create a field in the BC to use it in the Toggle Applet condition .Toggle Applet will be displayed when the drilldown is not required.

Second way you can achieve it is through visibility Type attribute in the drilldown object as well as visibility Applet Type attribue at the view level.